# SQL query with max date and multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have to count all orders which set the task_status to 'FULFILLED'. A specific task will be set to 'FULFILLED' if one order is 'SUCCESS' or if five orders with status are 'ATTEMPT'. I wrote a query which uses the max date to select the right orders. My problem is that the query sometimes counts (because of a same date as seen in the table) one 'ATTEMPT' as reason for a 'FULLFILLED' task although the actual reason is one 'SUCCESS' order. I need a query that prefers a 'SUCCESS' status (if existing) from an order over a 'ATTEMPT' status.

Thanks for help and advice!

This is my current query and an example of two orders with similar date:

```
select *,
    case 
        when task_status = 'FULFILLED' and status = 'SUCCESS' and max(date) then '999'
        when task_status = 'FULFILLED' and status = 'ATTEMPT' and max(date) then '999'
        else '000'
    end as number
    from table
    group by task_id
    ;


   task_id  order   task_status status  date
    372     121     FULFILLED   INVALID 2018/06/26
    372     132     FULFILLED   ATTEMPT 2018/07/04
    372     145     FULFILLED   SUCCESS 2018/07/04
```

Comment: i just cannot make sense of the question.  Sample data and desired results would help.  I can't figure out what you want at the task level and what you want at the order level.  Your query as written is going to result in syntax errors, so it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery getting the count of records for a task, where the status is `'ATTEMPT'` and check if it's at least five. To pick the records in the right order use `row_number()`. First order by `status` descending (because `'SUCCESS' > 'ATTEMPT'`) and then by the date, also descending. In an outer `SELECT` only get the records with a row number of one.

```
SELECT x.task_id,
       x.order,
       x.task_status,
       x.status,
       x.date
       FROM (SELECT t1.task_id,
                    t1.order,
                    t1.task_status,
                    t1.status,
                    t1.date,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.task_id
                                       ORDER BY t1.status DESC,
                                                t1.date DESC) rn
                    FROM table t1
                    WHERE t1.task_status = 'FULFILLED'
                          AND (t1.status = 'SUCCESS'
                                OR t1.status = 'ATTEMPT'
                                   AND (SELECT count(*)
                                               FROM table t2
                                               WHERE t2.task_id = t1.task_id
                                                     AND t2.tast_status = t1.task_status
                                                     AND t2.status = t1.status) >= 5)) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer sticky bit. When I only replace all 'x' with my  real table name I get a syntax error saying:                                                     
    : 1 - near "(": syntax error                                                                                I haven't found the problem yet.

Comment: @J.W.: `x` is an alias for the inner query. You don't need to replace it. The only thing you may need to replace is `table` in `FROM table t1`. (Or enclose `table` in double quotes like `"table"` if the table really is named `table`. Same may be true for the column `order` or any other identifiers clashing with key words.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in SQL. I replaced all 't1' with my real table name and identifiers clashing with keywords but still get the same error:P I also deleted both 'table'.

Comment: @J.W.: Again `t1` is an alias (so is `t2` by the way), you don't need to change them... Maybe the next time you just post your real table and column names then the query in in answer has a high chance to work out of the box...

Comment: I transferred the data to pgadmin 3 and tried to run it there. Pgadmin returns this error: ERROR:  relation "t1" does not exist
LINE 15:                     FROM t1.

Comment: Tank you, it worked. Thanks a lot for your help. You are awesome:)